# Making a 2D Array in UnityScript by making an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, unity-game-engine, unityscript, cellular-automata

So I'm working in Unity 3D with UnityScript trying to make a cave generator using cellular-automata. Here is my problem, I've created two variables, width and height, and they need to be the size of my 2D array. I've also created a function to generate the map upon startup, so the array needs to be initialized upon startup. I know I need some kind of `for` loop using `.length` and one of the variables, but I'm not entirely sure how to do this. Any help would be great!

Comment: post your code and we will help

Comment: I've found it is often easier to use a 1D array and address it two-dimensionally (in JS, calculate the coords).

Comment: Changed references to JavaScript to UnityScript since that's what it technically is. http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of the rows in your 2D array are the same length you don't need to write a loop, simply check the length of an arbitrary row i.e

```
var arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
];
var height = arr.length; //4
var width = arr[0].length; //3
```

An example where you would need to loop through is if all of the widths were of differing lengths i.e

```
var arr = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3, 4]
];

var widths = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  widths.push(arr[i].length);
}
console.log(widths); // [3, 4]
```

Here's how you generate a 2d array given the height and width

```
var height = 5,
width = 4;

var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
  arr[i] = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
    arr[i][j] = "x";
  }
}
console.log(arr);

// [ [ 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x' ],
//   [ 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x' ],
//   [ 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x' ],
//   [ 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x' ],
//   [ 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x' ] ]
```

Comment: The length and width of the array are determined by variables so I don't think I can instantiate this array without using a loop. For example the length of my array could be anywhere from 10-100 depending on how the generation works out, so that variable would need to be the length of the array. After I have that I would need to make each value within the first array have an array within it with a size equal to the second variable. The length and height wouldn't even be known until after I run the code. That is why I think I need to make the array using a loop. Thanks for taking time to look!

Comment: I edited my question to what I think answers your question. If that still doesn't help please post a sample of your code.

Comment: Thanks for your help Robert!

Answer (score 0):

Eh, in Unity you would just initialize them like this:

```
int gridSpace[,];
public int height;
public int width;

void Start()
{
   gridSpace = new int[height,width];
   MakeMapStuffHappen();
}
```

This will allow you to specify height and width in the editor (or programmatically)